# WPF custom DataGrid control doesn't show anything

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a custom DataGrid control.

The class as follows:

```
    public static class CloneRowDataGridCommands
    {
        private static RoutedCommand _cloneRowRoutedCommand = new RoutedCommand();
        public static RoutedCommand CloneRowRoutedCommand
        {
            get { return _cloneRowRoutedCommand; }
        }
    }

    public class CloneRowDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        protected Button CloneButton { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCloneColumnProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCloneColumn", 
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CloneRowDataGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnShowCloneColumnPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnShowCloneColumnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CloneRowDataGrid cloneRowDataGrid = d as CloneRowDataGrid;
            if (cloneRowDataGrid != null)
            {
                cloneRowDataGrid.OnShowCloneColumnPropertyChanged((bool) e.OldValue, (bool) e.NewValue);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnShowCloneColumnPropertyChanged(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
        {
            // Nothing right now
        }

        public static readonly RoutedEvent CloneEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Clone", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof(CloneRowRoutedEventHandler), 
                typeof (CloneRowDataGrid));

        public event CloneRowRoutedEventHandler Clone
        {
            add { AddHandler(CloneEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(CloneEvent, value); }
        }

        protected virtual void RaiseCloneEvent()
        {
            // TODO: change "new object()" to the row data
            CloneRowRoutedEventArgs args = new CloneRowRoutedEventArgs(CloneEvent, new object());
            RaiseEvent(args);
        }

        static CloneRowDataGrid()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(CloneRowDataGrid), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CloneRowDataGrid)));
        }

        public CloneRowDataGrid()
        {
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CloneRowDataGridCommands.CloneRowRoutedCommand,
                ExecuteCloneRow, CanExecuteCloneRow));
        }

        private void CanExecuteCloneRow(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void ExecuteCloneRow(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Clone row
            RaiseCloneEvent(); // pass object row to the eventargs
        }

        public bool ShowCloneColumn
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(ShowCloneColumnProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowCloneColumnProperty, value); }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            // Do stuff

            // TODO: Fix this to avoid memory lick if the event is already registered
            // TODO: Or change to a command for the clone button
            CloneButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_CloneButton") as Button;
            if (CloneButton != null)
            {
                CloneButton.Click += OnCloneButtonClick;
            }
        }

        private void OnCloneButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            // Invoke another event that might be registered from the client
            RaiseCloneEvent();
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInitialized(e);

            // Do stuff

        }

        protected override void OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(e);


        }
    }

    public delegate void CloneRowRoutedEventHandler(object sender, CloneRowRoutedEventArgs e);

    public class CloneRowRoutedEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
    {
        public object RowObject { get; protected set; }

        public CloneRowRoutedEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, object rowObject) : base(routedEvent)
        {
            RowObject = rowObject;
        }
    }
```

The style in Generic.xaml as follows.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type uiControls:CloneRowDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type uiControls:CloneRowDataGrid}">

                    <!-- Parameter should be the row -->
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When using the control.

```
<uiControls:CloneRowDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeListCustomers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="GridCustom"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DimGray" 
                          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" Margin="10,0,25,0" Height="200">
                            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                            <DataGrid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColorKey}" Color="White"/>
                            </DataGrid.Resources>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="CloneRowButtonColumn"/>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="75" >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="75" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="NickName" Width="100" >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding NickName}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </uiControls:CloneRowDataGrid>
```

What I get in designer and runtime is just a gray border with no columns. If I change the type tp DataGrid in the XAML window it shows 3 columns.

Definitely I'm missing something. I don't need anything special in styling, I just want DataGrid appearance and then work with additional functionality.

The goal is to have a column fixed and visible when needed with a flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, I actually had to remove the Property="Template" section and now the DataGrid styling applies. Though it feels like a hack and most probably need to know more about DataGrid styling override.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type uiControls:CloneRowDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">

</Style>
```